# Node Wrangler Viewer node's Emission Strength defaults to 16.667

Tags: node-editor, add-on

Is there a way to change back the Viewer node's Emission Strength to 1 by default?

Every time I ctrl+click on a node it creates a viewer node with the strength of 16.667 and I have to turn it down to 1 manually.

It only affects a single project, but I really want to avoid creating a new one just because of this problem.

Tried disabling the add-on, quitting, then reopening the project and enabling the add-on again.

Here's a stripped version of the blend file that shows the problem:
https://pasteall.org/media/b/7/b7f4473742b80110d3447d86bad9ed5b.blend

Comment: Hello, Have you tried disabling the add-on in the preferences, quitting then reopening the file and enabling it again ?

Comment: Same problem here, except the strength defaults to 0.177
Just tried disabling the addon, saving prefs, quitting Blender, reopen, enable addon, save prefs, same deal, default to 0.177.
It seems to affect only certain files.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem right now and finally, I discovered the reason.
The problem is that the node wrangler addon makes the correction of the emission value of the viewer node to be adjusted according to the exposure set on the color management section tab AND in the film section inside the render settings tab. It works fine with rendered mode but messes everything up in material preview mode.

I believe that re reason the color management does not have an effect on the material preview mode is probably to keep the values correct no matter the light conditions. I am not sure, though.

So, the tip here is: NEVER change the exposure in the color management or in the film section UNLESS you are going to render something or you are going to view the result on the render mode.